# android - Check what user select for location permission

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

I am researching about Location tracking for Android. When the permission popup shows, there are usually 3 options:

1. "While using the app"
2. "Only this time"
3. "Don't allow"

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to know which option user has selected.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a selection box for the different kinds of location permissions:

You can store the index of the selection box to a `int` variable.

Comment: actually, I have only one location permission. And there are 3 options with that location permission (please see the image). Can we edit the permission dialog?

Comment: Have YOU coded that app?

Comment: yes, I coded the app. But for the dialog, it provided by Android OS, not me.

Comment: I am not sure to be honest.You can always code your own dialog box if you dont like the premade dialog box :shrug:

Comment: I tried to search around but can't find the way.

Comment: Android Studio provides you the ability to implement your own visual tools so if you are not happy with the preexisting ones , just code one of your own <3.